# What is razorpay orders api and how to integrate it with react native?

Tags: react-native, razorpay

I am trying to implement a payment module in my react native app and trying to use Razorpay. As per documentation, there are two main things, the checkout, and the orders API. What is the difference between the two? What is exactly orders API and how is it to be used in react native? They have given many options in the docs to integrate the orders API like java, ruby, etc but nothing for react native. So any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Razorpay has integrated the checkout function for react-native, which means it will lead to the calling of [payment API](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/payments/#payment-entity), what this does is accepts payment from any user directly transferring the money without any details. With [orders API](https://razorpay.com/docs/api/orders/#order-entity), Razorpay enables you to create Orders that can be linked to payments. That means So that whatever payment arrives in your wallet is described with what has the payment related to. For example, suppose you have to show a product you wish to sell.

So first, you will have to create an order by calling orders API on your server-side, i.e. Node.JS or something else with request parameters like the amount, self-generated receipt number, and optional notes on who the user is. then after receiving the order_id, you will pass onto the mobile application and start the checkout functionality provided by react-native-razorpay.

Here is the example on how I used the react-native-razorpay.

On server-side - node.js:

```
const Razorpay = require("razorpay");
//...

let rzp = new Razorpay({
  key_id: "", // your `KEY_ID`
  key_secret: "" // your `KEY_SECRET`
});

//Inside Create Order Function

rzp.orders
  .create({
    amount: price * 100,
    currency: "INR",
    receipt: "", // Add receipt string
    payment_capture: 1, // auto capture payment config
    notes: { username, planId: id }
    // custom notes, you can use this in received response as key-value pair
  })
  .then(data => { // created order response
    let sendToApplicationResponse = { // Creating the response send to mobile app
      username,
      orderId: data.id,
      receipt: data.receipt
    };
    return sendToApplicationResponse;
  })
```

On react-native application-side:

```
import RazorpayCheckout from 'react-native-razorpay';

//.....

onPress={async () => {
//Call my server to create an Order 
// passing userId and price and plan selected as request parameters
// and waiting for the response
const response = await .....
// You can add parameters given in payment API
var options = {
  currency: 'INR',
  key: '', // add your razorpay key here
  amount: price * 100,
  order_id: response.data.orderId, // using the orderId which 
  prefill: { // add prefill details if you want
    contact: "",
    name: "",
  },
  payment_capture: 1,
};
// Call the razorpay checkout
RazorpayCheckout.open(options)
  .then(data => {
    console.log('RazorpayCheckout', data);
    Alert.alert('Payment Successful!');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    Alert.alert('Something went wrong!');
    // Alert.alert(`Error: ${error.code} | ${error.description}`);
  });
}}
```

Comment: Please help for above code where to write server code?